# Retrieve Decrypted Blame Info from SonarQube and SCM-Activity Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, sonarqube, blame

I am trying to write a plugin for SonarQube that uses the blame information provided by the SCM-Activity plugin.  The problem is that, in Sonar's database, *the blame information seems to either be **missing** or **encrypted***.

For example, I ran the following query against Sonar's database in MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT p.kee, m.name, pm.text_value
FROM sonar.project_measures pm
JOIN sonar.snapshots s on pm.snapshot_id = s.id
JOIN sonar.metrics m on m.id = pm.metric_id
JOIN sonar.projects p on s.project_id = p.id
WHERE s.root_project_id = 1 and m.domain = 'SCM';
```

Here's a sample of the result:

[image: SCM Query]

As you can see, there are four metrics that pertain to the SCM-Activity Plugin for SonarQube:

- authors_by_line
- revisions_by_line
- last_commit_datetimes_by_line
- scm.hash

So, here are my questions:

1. Why is it that scm.hash is the only metric that has any value in the column text_value, ***and the other metrics don't***?  (I tried the other columns in the project_measures table, and none of them seem to have any values either.)
2. How do I get useful, ***decrypted*** information from the scm.hash metric?  Is there a ruby method somewhere that I can use in the front end to get it?  (I figure there must be, or how else is SonarQube displaying the blame info when I drill down on lines?)
3. If there are Ruby methods that allow retrieval and ***decryption*** of blame info, they must be located in SonarQube's source code itself, as the SCM-Activity Plugin source code seems to be devoid of any Ruby.  If I am right, then ***where in SonarQube's source code are these Ruby methods located***?  I've been unable to find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see NULL values in "text_value" because those metrics need so store more than just a simple line of text. So you have to join the table "MEASURE_DATA" to get the value of those measures.

Comment: Fabrice, thank you!  This is exactly the missing puzzle piece that I was looking for.  You're awesome.

Comment: I cant see this table sonar DB. Can someone please look into below issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010513/sonarqube-line-based-scm-blame-information-where-its-stored